# Apache configuration - Point to a directory in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server with LAMP stack already installed.

I have a directory `/home/alex/checkhtml` which included some testing php and html.

What I want is when I access http://localhost/checkhtml , the content of `/home/alex/checkhtml` will be showed (Actually `/home/alex/checkhtml/index.html`)

Here is what I did:

1. Go to: /etc/apache2/conf-available and create `apache-php.conf` file
2. Add these lines to `apache-php.conf`:

   `Alias ^/php "/home/alex/php"
   <Directory /home/alex/php> 
       Order allow,deny
       Require all granted
   </Directory>`
3. Go to /home/alex/checkhtml and create `.htaccess` and add these lines:

   `<FilesMatch ".">
           Allow from all
   </FilesMatch>`
4. Enable `apache-php.conf` and restart apache

However, when I tried: http://localhost/checkhtml . The error appear:

```
The requested URL /checkhtml was not found on this server.
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong here ?

Thank you and best regards.

Alex

Comment: You want to access `/home/alex/checkhtml`, but you have created the rules in apache-php.conf for the path `/home/alex/php`

Comment: Sorry my copy and paste error.

Alias ^/checkhtml"/home/alex/checkhtml"
<Directory /home/alex/checkhtml> 
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Answer (score 0):

You should use Alias driective for exact URL matching. If you want to use Regex matching then use AliasMatch directive:

```
AliasMatch "^/checkhtml" "/home/alex/checkhtml"
<Directory /home/alex/checkhtml> 
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```